# I am unable to get the buttons to work in GUI any solutions?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

This is the code.
I am using pyCharm and python 3.7
I am able to get the GUI with all the buttons but when i click on the button it won't show in the display box until I click on the display box that is if i click on "5" it won't show in the display box until i click on the display box.
I am using MacOsCatalina.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from functools import partial

__version__ = "0.1"
ERROR_MSG = "ERROR"

     >The Main GUI class

class calcgui(QMainWindow):
 def __init__(self):
     super().__init__()
     self.setWindowTitle("calc")
     self.setFixedSize(300,300)
     self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
     self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
     self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
     self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
     self._createDisplay()
     self._createButtons()
 def _createDisplay(self):
         self.display = QLineEdit()
         self.display.setFixedHeight(50)
         self.display.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
         self.display.setReadOnly(True)
         self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.display)
 def _createButtons(self):
     self.buttons = {}
     buttonsLayout = QGridLayout()
     buttons = {"7":(0,0),
                 "8":(0,1),
                 "9":(0,2),
                 "C":(0,3),
                 "/":(0,4),
                 "4":(1,0),
                 "5":(1,1),
                 "6":(1,2),
                 "*":(1,3),
                 "(":(1,4),
                 "1":(2,0),
                 "2":(2,1),
                 "3":(2,2),
                 "-":(2,3),
                 ")":(2,4),
                 "0":(3,0),
                 "00":(3,1),
                 ".":(3,2),
                 "+":(3,3),
                 "=":(3,4)
         }
     for btnText, pos in buttons.items():
             self.buttons[btnText] = QPushButton(btnText)
             self.buttons[btnText].setFixedSize(50,50)
             buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.buttons[btnText],pos[0],pos[1])
             self.generalLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)

 def setDisplayText(self, text):
     self.display.setText(text)
     self.display.setFocus()

 def DisplayText(self):
     return self.display.text()

 def clearDisplay(self):
     self.setDisplayText("")

    >This is the linking class

class pycalcu:
 def __init__(self,model,view):
     self._evaluate = model
     self._view = view
     self._connectSignals()
 def _calculateResult(self):
     result = self._evaluate(expression=self._view.DisplayText())
     self._view.setDisplayText(result)
 def _buildExpression(self,sub_exp):
     if self._view.DisplayText() == ERROR_MSG:
         self._view.clearDisplay()
     expression = self._view.DisplayText() + sub_exp
     self._view.setDisplayText(expression)
 def _connectSignals(self):
     for btnText, btn in self._view.buttons.items():
         if btnText not in {"C","="}:
             btn.clicked.connect(partial(self._buildExpression,btnText))
     self._view.buttons["="].clicked.connect(self._calculateResult)
     return self._view.display.returnPressed.connect(self._calculateResult)
     self._view.buttons["C"].clicked.connect(self._view.clearDisplay)
def evaluateExpression(expression):
 try:
     result = str(eval(expression, {}, {}))
 except Exception:
     result = ERROR_MSG
 return result
def main():
 pycalc = QApplication(sys.argv)
 view = calcgui()
 view.show()
 model = evaluateExpression
 pycalcu(model=model,view=view)
 sys.exit(pycalc.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

Comment: Note in your code `self.generalLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)` this ought not be inside the For Loop as you only need to set this once you are done creating the `buttonsLayout`

Comment: Is this `>The Main GUI class` part of your code ?

Comment: Okay I took your code above commented out `>The Main GUI class` and `>This is the linking class` by adding a `#` in front of each and then moved `self.generalLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)` outside the For Loop and the code runs just fine producing the calculator you designed

Comment: ok i did that still the same problem the display doesn't show numbers or operators until i click on the display box.
Do you think it might be because of my OS.
and also the "C" button doesn't clear the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn’t really delve into your program logic.
I noted the changes that I made.
Give it a try.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QMainWindow,
                             QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from functools import partial

__version__ = "0.1"
ERROR_MSG = "ERROR"

#     >The Main GUI class

class calcgui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("calc")
        self.setFixedSize(300,300)

        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self._centralWidget)

        self._createDisplay()
        self._createButtons()

    def _createDisplay(self):
        self.display = QLineEdit()
        self.display.setFixedHeight(50)
        self.display.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.display.setReadOnly(True)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.display)

    def _createButtons(self):
        self.buttons = {}
        buttonsLayout = QGridLayout()
        buttons = {
                 "7":(0,0),
                 "8":(0,1),
                 "9":(0,2),
                 "C":(0,3),
                 "/":(0,4),
                 "4":(1,0),
                 "5":(1,1),
                 "6":(1,2),
                 "*":(1,3),
                 "(":(1,4),
                 "1":(2,0),
                 "2":(2,1),
                 "3":(2,2),
                 "-":(2,3),
                 ")":(2,4),
                 "0":(3,0),
                 "00":(3,1),
                 ".":(3,2),
                 "+":(3,3),
                 "=":(3,4)
        }
        for btnText, pos in buttons.items():
            self.buttons[btnText] = QPushButton(btnText)
            self.buttons[btnText].setFixedSize(50,50)
            buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.buttons[btnText],pos[0],pos[1])

        # <----    
        self.generalLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)                        # <----

    def setDisplayText(self, text):
        self.display.setText(text)
        self.display.setFocus()

    def DisplayText(self):
        return self.display.text()

    def clearDisplay(self):
        self.setDisplayText("")

#    >This is the linking class

class pycalcu:
    def __init__(self,model, view):
        self._evaluate = model
        self._view = view
        self._connectSignals()

    def _calculateResult(self):
        result = self._evaluate(expression=self._view.DisplayText())
        self._view.setDisplayText(result)

    def _buildExpression(self, sub_exp):
        if self._view.DisplayText() == ERROR_MSG:
            self._view.clearDisplay()
        expression = self._view.DisplayText() + sub_exp
        self._view.setDisplayText(expression)

    def _connectSignals(self):
        for btnText, btn in self._view.buttons.items():
            if btnText not in {"C", "="}:
                btn.clicked.connect(partial(self._buildExpression, btnText))
        self._view.buttons["="].clicked.connect(self._calculateResult)

        self._view.buttons["C"].clicked.connect(self._view.clearDisplay)        # +++

        return self._view.display.returnPressed.connect(self._calculateResult)

# ?        self._view.buttons["C"].clicked.connect(self._view.clearDisplay)     # ---

def evaluateExpression(expression):
    try:
        result = str(eval(expression, {}, {}))
    except Exception:
        result = ERROR_MSG
    return result

def main():
    pycalc = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = calcgui()
    view.show()

    model = evaluateExpression
    pycalcu(model=model, view=view)

    sys.exit(pycalc.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]